# Using python cx_Oracle, how do I call DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM, which has multiple declarations?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, dbms-metadata

Here's the call and error I currently receive:

```
cursor.callproc('DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM', ['DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM', 'STORAGE', 'false'])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM' match this call
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: This was cross posted and answered in https://community.oracle.com/thread/4319302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the use of quotations. The syntax for the procedure [`DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_metada.htm#i1000135)

```
DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM (
   transform_handle   IN NUMBER,
   name               IN VARCHAR2,
   value              IN VARCHAR2|IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE|IN NUMBER, 
   object_type        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL);
```

the last parameter(`object_type`) needn't to be specified obviously, since it has `NULL` value as default.

the penultimate parameter(`value`) might have three options for data type. Seems that is intended to be as `BOOLEAN`. So, remove quotes around `false`.

lastly, the first parameter(`transform_handle`) is also considered as numeric. So, remove quotes here too.

As a result, call the procedure as

```
cursor.callproc('DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM', 
                [DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'STORAGE', false]);
```

Comment: Good description of the issue and very close to working. It turns out that the DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM is a constant (defined as -1) in the Oracle space, but not in cx_oracle, so as written, this fails with an ORA-06502 (wrong datatype). Replacing that with an actual -1 works.